# How to inject @Published property into dataModel array

Tags: swiftui

I've followed a tutorial on building a pie chart, but can not figure out how to include dynamic values in the dataModel array.

The Observable class here provides calculated percentages.

```
class AllReport: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var walkPercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var dayCarePercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var stayPercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var dropInPercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var cancelledPercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var paidPercent: CGFloat = 0
    @Published var outstandingPercent: CGFloat = 0
    
}
```

Then the data being provided for the PieChart is as below...

```
struct TypePie : Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var percent: CGFloat
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    var icon: String
}

var typePieData = [
    
    TypePie(id: 0, percent: 60, name: "Walks", color: Color.green.opacity(0.6), icon: "groupWalk"),
    TypePie(id: 1, percent: 20, name: "Day Cares", color: Color.orange.opacity(0.6), icon: "time"),
    TypePie(id: 2, percent: 10, name: "Stays", color: Color.blue.opacity(0.6), icon: "shortStay"),
    TypePie(id: 3, percent: 3, name: "Drop Ins", color: Color.pink.opacity(0.6), icon: "dropIn"),
    TypePie(id: 4, percent: 7, name: "Cancellations", color: Color.red.opacity(0.6), icon: "cancel")
    
]
```

I need to change the placeholder values for each of the "percent" fields in "typePieData" array for the @Published values provided by the observableObject class "AllReport".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that observes an injected `AllReport` and uses key paths to access the correct property.

```
struct TypePie : Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    var icon: String
    @ObservedObject var source: AllReport
    var keyPath: KeyPath<AllReport, CGFloat>

    var percent: CGFloat {
        source[keyPath: self.keyPath]
    }
    var description: String {
        "\(name): \(percent)"
    }
}
```

And an example

```
var report = AllReport()
var typePieData = [

    TypePie(id: 0, name: "Walks", color: Color.green.opacity(0.6), icon: "groupWalk", source: report, keyPath: \.walkPercent),
    TypePie(id: 1, name: "Day Cares", color: Color.orange.opacity(0.6), icon: "time", source: report, keyPath: \.dayCarePercent),
    TypePie(id: 2, name: "Stays", color: Color.blue.opacity(0.6), icon: "shortStay", source: report, keyPath: \.stayPercent),
    TypePie(id: 3, name: "Drop Ins", color: Color.pink.opacity(0.6), icon: "dropIn", source: report, keyPath: \.dropInPercent),
    TypePie(id: 4, name: "Cancellations", color: Color.red.opacity(0.6), icon: "cancel", source: report, keyPath: \.cancelledPercent)

]
print(typePieData)
report.dayCarePercent = 12
print(typePieData)
report.stayPercent = 27
report.cancelledPercent = 5
print(typePieData)
```

> [Walks: 0.0, Day Cares: 0.0, Stays: 0.0, Drop Ins: 0.0, Cancellations: 0.0]
> [Walks: 0.0, Day Cares: 12.0, Stays: 0.0, Drop Ins: 0.0, Cancellations: 0.0]
> [Walks: 0.0, Day Cares: 12.0, Stays: 27.0, Drop Ins: 0.0, Cancellations: 5.0]

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you. I'm now able to pass the published properties into the model array without compiling errors. Unfortunately the published changes when the percentages are first calculated or re-calculated aren't being passed over yet, so I need to still figure out why that is. But that's not what this post is about so I'm marking your answer as correct with much appreciation. :)